# jquery element positioning problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone please tell me why my code below doesn't work? Code below should move my div to the left when pressing down the left arrow key and moving to the right when pressing down the right arrow key.  Thanks

```
 <html>                                                                  
 <head> 
<style type="text/css">
  #movingdiv {   color: #00FF00;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 18pt; left: 50px; width: 220px; background-color: yellow;}
</style>                                                                 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
   $("*").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left arrow key
    $("#movingdiv").animate({
      left: "-=900"
    });
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right arrow key
    $("#movingdiv").animate({
      left: "+=900"
    });
  }
});                                
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
   <div id="movingdiv">sdfsdfsdf</div>                                    
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add positioning CSS to the div:

position: absolute;
left: 50px;

http://jsfiddle.net/Canuteson/XZt98/